# Keyboard Shortcut for Caffeine Indiator

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Is there any way that I could setup a keyboard shortcut for `caffeine-indicator`. Or a command that I could run from the terminal. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Caffeine Indicator v2.8.3.

Comment: Can you specify more details

Comment: What type of details

Comment: You mean you want to start caffeine Indicator to start automatically?

Comment: A command to activate and deactivate it. It starts automatically at login already

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but maybe this will help to someone.

As it turned out, caffeine-indicator is just a python script located in /usr/bin/caffeine-indicator .
I've edited the script to allow for toggling upon keyboard shorcut.
Currently it's set to ctrl + t, but you can edit it to anything you want by changing the shorcut string in the code. Note that special keys have to be enclosed in <> and normal keys (like t) can't. Here's the edited script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
# Copyright © 2009-2020 The Caffeine Developers
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import os
import sys
from os.path import join, abspath, dirname, pardir, exists
import gettext
import locale
import logging
import argparse
import signal
import builtins
from subprocess import call
from pynput.keyboard import Key,HotKey,GlobalHotKeys
import threading
import pkg_resources
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AyatanaAppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk, GObject, AyatanaAppIndicator3 as AppIndicator3
from Xlib import display

PROGRAM_NAME = "caffeine-indicator"
VERSION = pkg_resources.require("caffeine")[0].version

run = True

# Register the gettext function for the whole interpreter as "_"
builtins._ = gettext.gettext

def get_base_path():
    c = abspath(dirname(__file__))
    while True:
        if exists(join(c, "share", PROGRAM_NAME)):
            return c

        c = join(c, pardir)
        if not exists(c):
            raise Exception("Can't determine BASE_PATH")

BASE_PATH = get_base_path()
GLADE_PATH = join(BASE_PATH, 'share', PROGRAM_NAME, 'glade')

# Set up translations
LOCALE_PATH = join(BASE_PATH, "share", "locale")

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

for module in locale, gettext:
    module.bindtextdomain(PROGRAM_NAME, LOCALE_PATH)
    module.textdomain(PROGRAM_NAME)

# Handle command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=PROGRAM_NAME, description='Toggle desktop idleness inhibition')
parser.add_argument('-V', '--version', action='version', version=PROGRAM_NAME + ' ' + VERSION)
parser.parse_args()

class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self, caffeine):
        self.Caffeine = caffeine
        self.Caffeine.connect("activation-toggled", self.on_activation_toggled)
        self.labels = [_("Activate"), _("Deactivate")]

        builder = Gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file(join(GLADE_PATH, "GUI.glade"))

        get = builder.get_object

        self.AppInd = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new("caffeine-cup-empty",
                                                  "caffeine",
                                                  AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
        self.AppInd.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)

        self.activate_menuitem = get("activate_menuitem")
        self.set_icon_is_activated(self.Caffeine.get_activated())

        # Popup menu
        self.menu = get("popup_menu")
        self.menu.show()
        self.AppInd.set_menu(self.menu)

        # About dialog
        self.about_dialog = get("aboutdialog")
        self.about_dialog.set_version(VERSION)
        self.about_dialog.set_translator_credits(_("translator-credits"))

        # Activate menu item shortcut
        self.AppInd.set_secondary_activate_target(self.activate_menuitem)

        builder.connect_signals(self)

    def on_activation_toggled(self, source, active, tooltip):
        self.set_icon_is_activated(active)

    def set_icon_is_activated(self, activated):
        # Toggle the icon, indexing with a bool.
        icon_name = ["caffeine-cup-empty", "caffeine-cup-full"][activated]
        self.AppInd.set_icon_full(icon_name, "Caffeine is {}".format("activated" if activated else "deactivated"))
        self.activate_menuitem.set_label(self.labels[self.Caffeine.get_activated()])

    # Menu callbacks
    def on_activate_menuitem_activate(self, menuitem, data=None):
        self.Caffeine.toggle_activated()
        menuitem.set_label(self.labels[self.Caffeine.get_activated()])

    def on_about_menuitem_activate(self, menuitem, data=None):
        self.about_dialog.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS)
        self.about_dialog.run()
        self.about_dialog.hide()

    def on_quit_menuitem_activate(self, menuitem, data=None):
        # Make sure desktop idleness is uninhibited
        global run
        run = False
        self.Caffeine.release()
        Gtk.main_quit()

def make_unmapped_window(wm_name):
    screen = display.Display().screen()
    window = screen.root.create_window(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, screen.root_depth)
    window.set_wm_name(wm_name)
    window.set_wm_protocols([])
    return window

class Caffeine(GObject.GObject):
    def __init__(self):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
        self.window = make_unmapped_window("Caffeine indicator")
        self.status_string = None
        self.screenSaverWindowID = None

    def get_activated(self):
        return self.screenSaverWindowID != None

    def toggle_activated(self):
        if self.screenSaverWindowID == None:
            self.screenSaverWindowID = hex(self.window.id)
            self.status_string = _(PROGRAM_NAME + " is inhibiting desktop idleness")
            logging.info(self.status_string)
            call(['xdg-screensaver', 'suspend', self.screenSaverWindowID])
        else:
            self.release()

        self.emit("activation-toggled", self.get_activated(), self.status_string)

    def release(self):
        if self.screenSaverWindowID != None:
            call(['xdg-screensaver', 'resume', self.screenSaverWindowID])
            self.screenSaverWindowID = None
            self.status_string = _(PROGRAM_NAME + " is inactive")
            logging.info(self.status_string)
            
            



def start_listener():
    # ctrl + t
    with GlobalHotKeys({
        "<ctrl>+t": on_release
    }) as h:
        while run:
            h.join(0.1)
        
        
def on_release():
    caffeine.toggle_activated()
    
    

# Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388088/python-gtk-signal-handler-not-working
def InitSignal(gui):
    def signal_action(signal):
        caffeine.release()
        sys.exit(1)

    def idle_handler(*args):
        GLib.idle_add(signal_action, priority=GLib.PRIORITY_HIGH)

    def handler(*args):
        signal_action(args[0])

    def install_glib_handler(sig):
        # GLib.unix_signal_add was added in glib 2.36
        GLib.unix_signal_add(GLib.PRIORITY_HIGH, sig, handler, sig)

    for sig in [signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGHUP]:
        signal.signal(sig, idle_handler)
        GLib.idle_add(install_glib_handler, sig, priority=GLib.PRIORITY_HIGH)


# Set up and run
l_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_listener, daemon=True)
l_thread.start()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
GObject.signal_new("activation-toggled", Caffeine,
        GObject.SignalFlags.RUN_FIRST, None, [bool, str])
caffeine = Caffeine()
gui = GUI(caffeine)
InitSignal(gui)
Gtk.main()
```

Note that you have to have pynput installed.